# How to use serialize() Method without using form Tag | Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I want add New Product without refresh the Page. So, I Use Bootstrap Model for to Add New Product.

If i use Form Tag model has been redirect same page. How to Avoid It. I am working in Laravel Project

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
 $("#add").click(function() {    
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: $("#add").attr('data-url'),
            data: {
             '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
            'form_data': $('#Form').serialize(),
            },
            success: function(data) {                   
                 $('#ledger_name').val('');
                 $('#openning_balance').val('0.00');
                 $('#ob_type').val('');
                 $('#under').val('');
                 $('#ledger_address').val('');                     
                 $("#newLedger .close").click();
                 alert("Data Inserted");
            },

         error: function(data)
            {
                var errors = '';
                for(datos in data.responseJSON){
                    errors += data.responseJSON[datos] + '<br>';
                }
                $('#response').show().html(errors); //this is my div with messages
            }

        });

    });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this on your beginning of your ajax call. do you want to refresh a div without reloading page???

```
event.preventDefault();
```